# How do I find the css of an element on a website

Tags: html, css

This is the website that its on: **http://demo.fabthemes.com/xenastore/**

I can not paste all the code from it because that wouldnt help, you need to see the actual individual element Im refering to!

Here is an image to help: http://s10.postimg.org/nyd6nwlfd/stac.png

The Green rectangle buttons that say the price, "$300", can you inspect the element and look at the coding, and tell me what the font name, size is?

If you could tell me all the info needed (Font size, Weight, name, etc...) that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Good font, reasonable size!

Answer (score 4):

```
font-family: Open Sans,Arial,Century gothic,sans-serif;
font-weight: 800;
color: #fff;
font-size: 16px;
```

In Google Chrome - right click the element that you want to inspect, and choose inspect element.  On the right side will have the css class with all the properties.  All of the css classes under that one on the right are what that element you selected inherited from other classes.

In FireFox you need to first download the plugin FireBug, then it is the same process.

**UPDATE:**

**Why are there so many different fonts?**
because the browser will use the first one that it understands, if Open Sans can not be found it moves to the next one, ect.

its always good to have some back up fonts that are similar to the one you want for browsers that don't support your first choice.  Another option is to include the font that you want into your project [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/) has a bunch of free fonts to use with very simple instructions on how to add to you project.

Comment: Sorry about that discussion going sideways. I've wiped the comments. Seems we need to keep an eye on things.

Comment: @BoltClock - yea thanks , it was getting a little out of control